# Insufficient permission of accessing table from usrr

Tags: oracle

I have created table it's sequence on owner .

Also granted permission of insert update delete select on table from owner to user.

Also granted select on sequence from owner to user.

Finally I logged in user and created synonym for owner table and sequence.

Now when I access table in user it throws insufficient permission.the same table can be accessible in owner..

Any idea what I'm missing here..

Comment: Could you copy/paste the last step you did (the way you tried to access the table and error you got)?

Comment: Select * from  <table> exact error I will paste it later as just escaped from office

Comment: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
Error at Line: 1 Column: 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue got resolved as issue with grant statement I gave incorrect user id

Answer (score 0):

You should execute these queries and verify grantor and grant:

```
select * from all_tab_privs where table_name   ='YOUR_NAME_SEQUENCE';
select * from all_tab_privs where table_name   ='YOUR_NAME_TABLE';
select * from all_synonyms  where synonym_name ='YOUR_NAME_TABLE';
```

Certainly Grantor not equal to your user or some grant is missed.

Thank you.